# Do Rails/Haml/Sass execute slower than Node/Express/Jade/Stylus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, express

I'm not sure if it is my imagination but this is what I've experienced:

- When I use SASS (--watch), save the .sass file and switch to the browser very fast (1~2 seconds) sometimes the changes are not being reflected. With jade/stylus the changes don't delay at all.
- I noticed that it takes more time to install a gem than a node module.
- Starting an Node.js/Express.js server takes me like 1 second. Starting a Rails server takes me like 3~4 seconds.
- Also noticed that node frameworks (e.g. Express.js) generate files faster.

Now I'm not sure if it is because Node.js/Express.js are younger projects and have fewer features or it is because Node.js is actually faster?

(I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with an AMD CPU).

Comment: Seems like you have your answers. Obviously, *for you*, they do. What did you hope to gain from this question? They're two completely unrelated pieces of software, doing completely different things, implemented in completely different ways. Comparing their load times isn't useful.

Comment: Are you talking about benchmarking the server-side compilation of the CSS? or the performance of the stack in a production environment? Either way, alt-tabbing and counting mississippi's is a silly way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **Ruby is slow**. It's a huge trouble for rubyists and is a purpose for many hot discussions like *"does something faster than Ruby?"*.

Javascript runs fast even on virtual machine. It is even faster than native Ruby interpreter.

But i prefer **Ruby** and **Ruby on Rails** because of its much more stable library set, huge community and because of Ruby's syntax. It's really sweet =)